# How to show entry meta values below post

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

How can I show my categories, tags, author date, icon tags
below my blog post? ATM they appear above post.

I want them to appear below the post just over read more button.

I tried to find entry meta div class in single.php so that I can place it below but failed so need help
Minamaze theme https://wordpress.org/themes/minamaze

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that would be in `index.php`

move the div with the class 'entry-meta'